# Need help checking and verifying that my proofs are correct.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

Using these field axioms: [1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T82iz.png)
[2.][2.]

3. Prove that for all $a,\, b\in\mathbb R$, $ab>0$ if and only if $a>0$ and $b>0$, or $a<0$ and $b<0$.
   In other words, $ab$ is positive if and only if either $a$ and $b$ are both positive or both negative.

   There are two directions, starting with the first direction:

   Assume $a>0$ and $b>0$.  Then it is clear $ab>0$ by (B4).  Similarly, if $a<0$ and $b<0$, then $ab=(-1)(-1)|a||b|=|a||b|>0$ also by (B4).

   In handling the harder direction:

   Assume $ab>0$.

   Clearly, neither $a=0$ or $b=0$, otherwise we would have $ab=0$ by (B4) which is not the case.  So $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$.

   Now assume that $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs (without loss of generality, we can let $a>0$ and $b<0$, both by (problem2)).  Then $ab=(-1)|a||b|=-|a||b|<0$ which is not the case.

   Thus, we either have $a$ and $b$ be both positive, or both negative.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 is good, except you did too much! You didn't need to prove the converse.

In part 2, I think you should justify why, if $c < 0$ and $b - a > 0$, then $c(b - a) < 0$. This is not part of the order axioms. I also think that $c(b - a) = cb - ca$ needs to be further justified (did you really mean to refer to (A3), the existence of a unique additive identity?).

I understand that there may be propositions that you've proven earlier that will help you (e.g. maybe you know that if $x < 0$ and $y > 0$ then $xy < 0$), but you should refer to them, not vaguely to the axioms that will help prove them.

Part 3 has some similar issues. Do you know that $-a = (-1)a$? You have to remember that $-a$ is the unique number $x$ such that $x + a = 0$. How do you know that the number that satisfies this equation is $(-1)a$? You also seem to assume that $(-1)(-1) = 1$ and $a0 = 0b = 0$ (I don't see how axiom (B4) obviously proves this). You finally refer back to problem 2 to justify that $x < 0$ and $y > 0$ imply $xy < 0$, even though this was an assumption used to prove part 2!

So, you've got a few holes to plug.

Comment: @TheoBandit , for part two I did mean A3, not A7, sorry. Moreover, Can I say by A7 that we know -a=(-1)a? Or perhaps A8? And do any of the B field axioms apply for 3? Thank you

Comment: No, $-a = (-1)a$ is not an obvious consequence of just A7. While this is definitely a property of the number 1, which is defined by A7 and A8, the $-$ in front of it is an artefact of the additive group. You'll need to appeal to A9, the distributive law, as this is a property of how $+$ and $\cdot$ interoperate. The same is true for $a0 = 0b = 0$, and $(-1)(-1) = 1$. Here's something to get you started: $$0a + 0a = (0 + 0)a = 0a \implies 0a + 0a + -(0a) = 0a + -(0a) \implies 0a + 0 = 0 \implies 0a = 0$$

Comment: As for your other question, yes, you will need the order axioms for ordered fields, as there is an inequality involved. You will need the fourth property, as you are dealing with multiplication. You will also need the third property, as the fourth property deals only with multiplication by positive numbers. In order to make negative numbers, this is a property of addition, and the third property tells you how $<$ interacts with $+$. Try proving the assumed properties I've pointed out. If you get anywhere, ask another question, and put a comment here linking to the new question.